# Uninstalling node on OSX Yosemite doesn't work

Tags: node.js, uninstallation

I tried uninstalling NodeJS by following all the commands I've seen in various SO posts. I found the folders necessary to delete, delete them, reboot, and still, typing `node --version` shows it's not really uninstalled. Why is this?

How can I locate where those executable `node` or `npm` commands exist when I type it in my terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
which node
```

To see which version of node is getting executed when you enter the command